# Azure APIM: new Developer portal requires CORS to test the API

Tags: cors, azure-api-management

I'm trying to configure my API in Azure APIM so it can be called by the new Azure APIM Developer Portal (still in preview at the moment).
When I try to call the API from the dev portal, I have an error telling me that I need to configure CORS to allow a call from the dev portal.
I added the CORS policy to my API (with origin=*, for testing purposes) and I still have the same issue.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to adjust it, but this should do the trick:

```
<cors>
    <allowed-origins>
        <origin>*</origin>
    </allowed-origins>
    <allowed-methods>
        <method>*</method>
    </allowed-methods>
    <allowed-headers>
        <header>*</header>
    </allowed-headers>
    <expose-headers>
        <header>*</header>
    </expose-headers>
</cors>
```

Comment: Thanks but I applied this policy on the product level, just after the base policy, and I still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did this at the all API operations level and had to include 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

```
<cors allow-credentials="true">
    <allowed-origins>
        <origin>*YourDomain*</origin>
    </allowed-origins>
    <allowed-methods>
        <method>GET</method>
        <method>POST</method>
    </allowed-methods>
    <allowed-headers>
        <header>Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key</header>
        <header>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</header>
        <header>Content-Type</header>
    </allowed-headers>
</cors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact policy that should be applied:

```
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>GET</method>
                <method>POST</method>
                <method>PUT</method>
                <method>DELETE</method>
                <method>HEAD</method>
                <method>OPTIONS</method>
                <method>PATCH</method>
                <method>TRACE</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
            <expose-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </expose-headers>
        </cors>
```

Source: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/290#issuecomment-551088484